# Batch curl -d from JSON file

Tags: json, bash

I have a JSON file and I would like to pass each object to a `curl -d` command :

```
[
{
    "number":"+336770002979",
    "message":"La plupart\ntest",
    "sender":"BEcompany",
    "date": 1539286620000
},
{
    "number":"+336600000780",
    "message":"La plupart\ntest",
    "sender":"BEcompany",
    "date": 1539286620000
},
...
]
```

For now I tried this

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155eed9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d @json.json \
https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
```

but it only reads the first object.

### Edit

I fixed the `[...]` in the JSON and the curl command based on the comments.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If you have multiple objects, they need to be in an array.

Comment: If you add the array brackets, you should be able to use `jq` to split it up, then loop through them in the shell script and run `curl` with each of them.

Comment: You have mismatched quotes in your command.

Comment: @Louis - Please give a small but complete example of the input.  Is it supposed to a single JSON document, a stream of such documents, or ...?

Comment: @peak I'd like to do exactly what @Barmar suggested : loop through all the objects in the json document and pass them to the `curl -d` command. I can choose the format because I am the one who's exporting it. But I think a single json document would be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jq -c .[]` to split the file to one array element per line, and take it from there.

```
jq -c .[] json.json |
while IFS= read -r fragment; do
    curl -options -etc -d "$fragment" "http://url"
done
```

Comment: @peak Absolutely correct, egg on my face; thanks, updated!

Comment: now can you help me figure out how to repeat the same batch of message for several phone numbers ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780300/bash-double-loop-over-two-json-files-to-command