# A Bash double loop over two JSON files to command

Tags: bash

I run this curl command for every object in a json file

```
jq -c '.[]' json.json |
while IFS= read -r fragment; do
    curl -X POST \
        -H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155c6ad9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "$fragment" \
        https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
done
```

json file:

```
[
    {
        "number": "+336000287407",
        "message": "Bonjour :)\nNou corps.\n\n",
        "sender": "BEinstitute",
        "date": 1539367199999
    },
    {
        "number": "+336000287407",
        "message": "J'inspire, ps aujourd'hui de faire votre pratique quotidienne.",
        "sender": "BEinstitute",
        "date": 1539421199999
    },
    {
        "number": "+336000287407",
        "message": "En devenant re votre pratique quotidienne.",
        "sender": "BEinstitute",
        "date": 1539507599999
    },
    {
        "number": "+336000287407",
        "message": "Ralentir le flot ",
        "sender": "BEinstitute",
        "date": 1539593999999
    },
    ...
    ]
```

And now I would like to do the same batch process, but for each phone number in the following file :

```
[
    {"number": "+33627000287407"},
    {"number": "+33608000066706"},
    {"number": "+31611355000094"},
    {"number": "+33678490800060"},
    {"number": "+33600063849305"},
    {"number": "+33640003179187"},
    {"number": "+33652000281148"},
    {"number": "+33671000740645"},
    {"number": "+33611900049942"},
    {"number": "+33667100022316"},
    {"number": "+33607720009877"}
]
```

How can I figure this out?

Comment: What does *"so it replaces the "number": value by the current phone number.*" mean? And what relevance does this first chunk of code and file have with the question? Are they related, or is it just a similar-ish example?

Comment: sorry it was unclear. I need the first file to be run for each phone number in the second file

Comment: Doesn't that API you are sending to need the `message`, `sender`, and `date` in that format or is it cool to just send it a number? If it is cool to just send it a number, then your existing solution will work fine here, just point it at the different file. ALSO you should probably remove your API key from the question. I'm assuming that is a key specific to your user at that site/api?

Comment: So [looking here](https://www.primotexto.com/api/sms/notification.asp) it shows that `message` is a required parameter for the API. So you'll have to cook up a canned message here for that numbers-only file like `jq '[.[] | {number, message:"some message"}]'`

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you are doing. Are you wanting to loop through the numbers in `numeros.json` and for each of those, get the relevant json from the `json.json` file and send to the API?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a bit of a guess here:

You have a file named `numeros.json` with a list of numbers. You want to loop through that list of numbers and for each of them find a match in `json.json`. For each match you want to submit it to the API. This would explain the "loop in a loop" which is a reasonable way to go about this.

You could also just go about this by piping the `numeros.json` fragments to your second `jq` using `xargs` as the middle man to pass the values::

```
    jq '.[] | .number ' numeros.json | xargs -I {} jq -c --arg num {} '.[] | select(.number==$num)' json.json |
    while IFS= read -r fragment; do
            curl -X POST \
                -H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: <<<YOURAPIKEY>>>" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -d "$fragment" \
                 https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
    done
```

Your original `jq` on `json.json` gets a bit more complex here because we need to use the `--args` flag to capture the number and the `select()` in `jq` to do the searching.

Instead of xargs though, you can totally use your `for` loop like in your answer, but I would suggest switching your second `jq` as I have it here to perform the search for numbers.

```
for phone in $(jq -r '.[] | .number' numeros.json); do
    jq -c --arg num "$phone" '.[] | select(.number==$num)' json.json |
    while IFS= read -r fragment; do
            curl -X POST \
                -H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: <<<YOURAPIKEY>>>" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -d "$fragment" \
                 https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
    done
done
```

Comment: It's similar. I just moved the searching into the `jq` script. I also am 100% positive that --slurpfile to bring in the `numeros.json` into a single `jq` script is viable here. I'm just not familiar enough with `jq` to figure out how to do that. I assume the `map()` function would be utlized. Then you have just one call to `jq` before bumping out to your loop.

Comment: ok thanks a lot ! Quik question: how can I make the script stop if the curl command returns an error ?

Comment: `curl stuff || break` will break out of the loop if `curl stuff` returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is working:

```
for phone in $(jq -r '.[] | .number' numeros.json); do
jq -c '.[]' json.json |
while IFS= read -r fragment; do
    fragment=$(sed -e"s/+33677592979/$phone/;" <<< $fragment);
    curl -X POST \
        -H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155c6a3c99d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "$fragment" \
        https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
done
done
```